# Have Android App communicate to PHP file

Tags: java, php, android, database

I'm trying to have my android app communicate with my friends PHP file which stores data into our database and then registers that data for a new user account.  I am new to PHP but I can read it.  But whatever I try, nothing seems to be able to be passing the values through to his post requests.  I've tried everything from Volley Requests to JSON Parsing and I cant get it to work.

Here is his PHP file.

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//$user = (int)$_POST['user_id'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password1 = $_POST['psw'];
$password2 = $_POST['psw-repeat'];
$first = $_POST['first_name']; 
$last = $_POST['last_name']; 

//<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me

include 'connRW.php';

$stmt = $connRW->prepare("SELECT * FROM AdUsers WHERE email = :email or 
fb_email 
= :fb_email");
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue(':fb_email', $email);
$stmt->execute();

$row1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $connRW->prepare("SELECT * FROM AdPublishers WHERE email = :email or 
fb_email = :fb_email");
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue(':fb_email', $email);
$stmt->execute();

$row2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$row1 && !$row2 && $password1)
{
if ($password1 == $password2) {
    $pwsaltedhashed = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt = $connRW->prepare("SELECT raadz_user_id FROM GetNext");
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $next_user_id = $row["raadz_user_id"] + 1;

    $stmt = $connRW->prepare("UPDATE GetNext SET raadz_user_id = 
:next_user_id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':next_user_id', $next_user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $connRW->prepare("INSERT INTO AdUsers ( raadz_user_id, email, 
password, first_name, last_name )
             VALUES ( :user_id, :email, :password, :first_name, :last_name 
)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $next_user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $pwsaltedhashed);
    $stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $first);
    $stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $last);
    $stmt->execute();

    $confirm_string = $next_user_id . substr($first, 0, 2) . substr($last, 
0, 2);
```

And this is my Java class in Android Studio I'm using:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvLogin;
Button bRegister;
EditText etEmail;
EditText etPassword;
EditText etPasswordRepeat;
EditText etfirstName;
EditText etlastName;
String url = "https://example.com/usersignup.php";
String gEmail;
String gPassword;
String gPasswordRepeat;
String gFirst;
String gLast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etPasswordRepeat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordRepeat);
    etfirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    etlastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    tvLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLogin);
    bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    gEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
    gPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();
    gPasswordRepeat = etPasswordRepeat.getText().toString();
    gFirst = etfirstName.getText().toString();
    gLast = etlastName.getText().toString();


    tvLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String url = "https://raadz.com/usersignup.php";
            StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response.contains("Message could not be send.")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if(response.contains("Message has been sent")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    //This code is executed if the server responds, whether or not the response contains data.
                    //The String 'response' contains the server's response.
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //This code is executed if there is an error.
                }
            }) {
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    MyData.put("email", gEmail);
                    MyData.put("psw", gPassword);
                    MyData.put("psw-repeat", gPasswordRepeat);
                    MyData.put("first_name", gFirst);
                    MyData.put("last_name", gLast);

                    return MyData;
                }
            };



MySingleton.getInstance(getAppContext()).addToRequestQueue(MyStringRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Without having gotten too much into your code: The question as such is wrong.

Your Android App cannot communicate with "a PHP file".

What it can do is to call/consume a restful web service implemented in PHP. Yet, since your communication protocol is HTTP, it does not matter which technology is hiding behind the restful API (could be PHP, Java, Erlang, Python... whatever), let alone to understand the code.

That being said, you might want to search for "android call restful service" or the like -- plenty of examples can be found.